# How to derive the representation formula from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation, harmonic-functions

> Prove that in $\mathbb R^2$, we have the following representation formula for harmonic function $u$:$$u(\vec x_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\partial D}\left(u(\vec x)\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec n}(\ln|\vec x-\vec x_0|)-\ln|\vec x-\vec x_0 |\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}(\vec x)\right)\,\mathrm ds.$$

In class we  found the representation formula in $\mathbb R^3$, which is
$$u(\vec x_0)=\frac{1}{4\pi}\iint_{\partial D}\left(-u(\vec x)\frac{\partial}{\partial \vec n}\left(\frac{1}{| \vec x-\vec x_0|}\right)+\frac{1}{|\vec x-\vec x_0 |}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec n}(\vec x)\right)\,\mathrm dA.$$

In the process we did not use at all the Dirac delta function. I have seen a proof<sup>*</sup> for the representation formula in $\mathbb R^2$ using that function and Heavyside-function as well, but I did not understand this part: $$v(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\log| x- x_0|$$ satisfies the identity $$\Delta v=\delta(x-x_0).$$

Could someone explain with details that part?

---

Alternatively, how to use the representation formula in $\mathbb R^3$ to prove in $\mathbb R^2$? If you see Chee Han comment, maybe could help although I did not understand his comment.

Please help me with the proof.

---

Proof<sup>*</sup>

[image]

Comment: The proof is essentially the same as $R^3$. You want to apply Green's identity $\int_D (u\Delta v - v\Delta u) dx = \int_{\partial D} (u\partial_nv - v\partial_nu) ds$ but this is not applicable because $\ln|x - x_0|$ has a singularity at $x = x_0$. So need to cut an $\epsilon$ ball around $x_0$ from $D$.

Comment: @CheeHan Could you elaborate in an answer please?

Comment: to cut an $\epsilon$ ball around $x_0$ from D? wut

Comment: That means a ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered on $x_0$, in the region $D$. This ball needs to be cut out because it contains a singularity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$Without getting into technical details of generalized functions, here is a classical method to verify the identity.

Assume that $D$ is an open and bounded area in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with $C^1$ boundary. Suppose $B(x_0, 2r_0) \subseteq D$. Since $u \in C^1(\overline{B(x_0, r_0)})$, then there exists $M > 0$ such that $|∇u| \leqslant M$ on $\overline{B(x_0, r_0)}$. Note that $∆v = 0$ on $D \setminus \{x_0\}$. For $0 < ε < \min(r_0, 1)$, applying Green's second identity on $D \setminus B(x_0, ε)$,\begin{align*}
0 &= \int\limits_{D \setminus B(x_0, ε)} (u∆v - v∆u) \,\d x = \int\limits_{\partial (D \setminus B(x_0, ε))} \left( u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} - v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \right) \,\d s\\
&= \int\limits_{\partial D} \left( u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} - v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \right) \,\d s - \int\limits_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} \left( u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} - v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \right) \,\d s,
\end{align*}
thus$$
\int\limits_{\partial D} \left( u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} - v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \right) \,\d s = \int\limits_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} \,\d s - \int\limits_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \,\d s. \tag{1}
$$

Because$$
\left. \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} \right|_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} = \left. \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} \right|_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left( \frac{1}{2π} \ln r \right) \right|_{r = ε} = \frac{1}{2πε}
$$
and $u$ is continuous at $x_0$, then$$
\lim_{ε → 0^+} \int\limits_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} \,\d s = \lim_{ε → 0^+} \frac{1}{2πε} \int\limits_{\partial B(x_0, ε)} u \,\d s = u(x_0).
$$
Because $|∇u| \leqslant M$ on $B(x_0, ε) \subseteq \overline{B(x_0, r_0)}$, then\begin{align*}
&\peq \left| \ \int\limits_{\smash{\partial B(x_0, ε)}} v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \,\d s \right| = \left| \ \int\limits_{\smash{\partial B(x_0, ε)}} v ∇u · \vec{n} \,\d s \right|\\
&\leqslant \int\limits_{\smash{\partial B(x_0, ε)}} |v∇u| · |\vec{n}| \,\d s \leqslant M \int\limits_{\smash{\partial B(x_0, ε)}} |v| \,\d s\\
&= M \int_{-π}^π \left( -\frac{\ln ε}{2π} \right) · ε \,\d θ = -M ε \ln ε,
\end{align*}
which implies$$
\lim_{ε → 0^+} \int\limits_{\smash{\partial B(x_0, ε)}} v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \,\d s = 0.
$$
Making $ε → 0^+$ in (1),$$
\int\limits_{\partial D} \left( u \frac{\partial v}{\partial \vec{n}} - v \frac{\partial u}{\partial \vec{n}} \right) \,\d s = u(x_0).
$$

Comment: Should not be double integral in the first integral that you wrote?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the proof, I'm not sure what you proved. Is this $\nabla v=\delta(x-x_0)$ _satisfies_ _$\iint_u(x)\delta(x-x_0)dx=u_0$_ what you showed?

Comment: ooh nice to know that kind of notation, so $\int(\dots)dx$ could mean a n-integral if $x\in\mathbb R^n$

Comment: Here $\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_{\partial B(x_0,\epsilon)}uds=u(x_0)$ you mean $u$ evaluated in $x_0$ or it's a multiplication $u*x_0$?

Comment: I think it means an evaluation, but I don't how did you find it. When $\epsilon\to0^+,$ it goes to $x_0$?

Comment: @user441848 This is a standard result about continuous functions. Note that $\frac1{2πε}\int_{∂B(x_0,ε)}\,\mathrm ds=1$, then\begin{align*}&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}\left|\frac1{2πε}\int\limits_{∂B(x_0,ε)}u\,\mathrm ds-u(x_0)\right|=\frac1{2πε}\left|\ \int\limits_{∂B(x_0,ε)}(u(x)-u(x_0))\,\mathrm ds\right|\\&\leqslant\frac1{2πε}\int\limits_{∂B(x_0,ε)}|u(x)-u(x_0)|\,\mathrm ds\leqslant\sup_{x\in ∂B(x_0,ε)}\|u(x)-u(x_0)\|→0.\quad(x→x_0)\end{align*}

Comment: What does this mean $u \in C^1(\overline{B(x_0, r_0)})$?

Comment: And to your last comment why $\frac1{2πε}\int_{∂B(x_0,ε)}\,\mathrm ds=1?$

Comment: And why $u \in C^1(\overline{B(x_0, r_0)})$ implies the existence of $M>0$ such that $\vert \nabla u\vert\le M$ in $\overline {B(x_0,r_0)}$?

Comment: Why $\nabla^2 v=0$ in $D\{x_0\}$ ?

Comment: And the last one :)  why $\vert v\vert=-\frac{\ln\epsilon}{2\pi}$?

Comment: Apologies for the bunch of questions, good thing is I understood the rest of the proof.

Comment: @user441848 The fact that $\frac1{2πε}\int_{∂B(x_0,ε)}\,\mathrm ds=1$ is because for any regular curve $L$, $\int_L\mathrm ds$ is just the length of $L$. And $Δv=0$ on $D\setminus\{x_0\}$ is because (wlog assume that $x_0=(0,0)$)$$v_{x_1x_1}=\frac1{2π}\frac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}=-v_{x_2x_2}.$$Finally, $v=\frac{\ln ε}{2π}$ on $∂B(x_0,ε)$ is because $|x-x_0|=ε$ for $x\in∂B(x_0,ε)$.

Comment: In your last line of your last comment, why didn't you consider the absolute bars and the minus sign in $v=\frac{\ln \epsilon}{2\pi}?$

Comment: @user441848 $v=\frac{\ln ε}{2π},\ 0<ε<1\Rightarrow|v|=-\frac{\ln ε}{2π}$.

Comment: ah :) .And why in this case did you consider $0<\epsilon<1$ and not $0<\epsilon<r_0$?

Comment: oh ok. Could you explain with more detail the part of $\Delta v=0$ on $D-\{x_0\}?$. I  can't see where does this come from $v_{x_1x_1}=\frac1{2π}\frac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}=-v_{x_2x_2}$

Comment: @user441848 Assume $x_0=(0,0)$. Since $v(x_1,x_2)=\frac1{4π}\ln(x_1^2+x_2^2)$, then$$v_{x_1}=\frac1{4π}·\frac{1}{x_1^2+x_2^2}·2x_1=\frac1{2π}·\frac{x_1}{x_1^2+x_2^2},\\v_{x_1x_1}=\frac1{2π}·\frac{1·(x_1^2+x_2^2)-x_1·2x_1}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}=\frac1{2π}·\frac{x_2^2-x_1^2}{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}.$$The other one is analogous.

Comment: Oh I see, and also noticing this $\Delta v=\nabla^2v=v_{x_1x_1}+v_{x_2x_2}=0$ right?

Comment: @user441848 Yes.

Comment: I don't see why you can still apply Green's Second Identity in R^2. Green's Second Identity is a direct consequence of the Divergence Theorem which holds in R^3.  In R^2 we only have Green's Formula though.